# Page-tempate with its own documentlibrary?

Tags: template, project-templates

Is it possible to create a page-template that will also create its own library? As for now i am creating new project-pages using a site as template. But it would be better if i can keep it all in one site, and instead make new projects with site-pages. Problem is each project needs its own library. (And lists actally) + a project-page.